# sql server export data tier application

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am working on SQL Server 2012 and 2014, I want to generate database's `.bacpac` file through `Export data-tier application` wizard we can generate the file and import on another server.

Is it possible to generate the `.bacpac` from Tsql (SQL query) syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from T-SQL as it is not a SQL function performing this operation, you can do this either from powershell or the wizard in SSMS:

[Extract a DAC From a Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231291.aspx)

Or you you can use the command line based SqlPackage.exe:

[SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)